# Delete entire row in excel shouldn't delete the button present in the same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

I have my data from column A to column F in an excel sheet.

I have created a button in other columns somewhere in the mid of the page like H5

No when i delete the invalid data manually by just selecting the row number and delete that should delete the entire row.

But my requirement is we should be deleting the entire row for ex: if row 5 has invalid data.

We will delete the invalid row by selecting row 5 and delete.But we do have a button in the same row of H column.
The requirement is that the button shouldn't be deleted.

Is there any way where i can retain the button even the entire row is deleted.I tried locked cells,panes and splits.

But no luck.
Could you please help me in this ?

Comment: subject and post seem to contradict each other, What type of button is it,is it linked to a cell and you want the button kept or deleted?

Comment: sorry @Steven Martin.i have corrected it now..do you know if there is a way other than macro recording to delete the rows only until column F and freeze the rest of the columns in that row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click the button, choose "Format Control" and under Properties choose "Don't Move or Size with Cells." This works for both Forms and ActiveX type buttons.

Comment: Is there any way where i can restrict my deletion only to the columns A till column F..and retain all the data in rest of the columns

Comment: The answer is yes. Try doing what you want with the Macro Recorder on. If you get stuck you know where to find us :)

Comment: @DougGlancy...ok macro recorder is a good option..is there any way where we can achieve this without macro recorder..i have a button click event too in this..

Comment: The macro recorder is just to generate some code that you can then modify and use where you need it. It's a good way to learn methods and syntax.